# Object doesn't support property or method 'readFile' (node: fs)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fs

TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'readFile'

I've just created a brand new react app, but this is happening... 
I don't know what else I can do.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as zlib from 'zlib';


    constructor(props: IReactComponentProps, state: IReactComponentState) {
        super(props, state);
        this.jsonPath = "/myfolder/mygzipedjsonfile.json.gz";

        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            error: false,
        };

        this.test();
    }

    private test() {

        fs.readFile(this.jsonPath, function (err, buffer) {
            console.log('success');
        });
    }
```

Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'readFile'

```
ReactComponent.prototype.test
C:/Source/new-teste/src/ReactComponent.tsx:44
  41 | 
  42 |    private test() {
  43 | 
> 44 |        fs.readFile(this.jsonPath, function (err, buffer) {
     |        ^
```

Comment: You should use an `<input type="file">` element and have the user select the file. Javascript in the browser can't select files without the user's permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `fs` on the client side. It will not work in browsers so as to protect your file system from potential security threats, `fs` is a low-level ( OS ) Node.js-specific package. By experience I do all my file processing server-side so I use [`zlib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) but again, it is node.js- specific. I can suggest [`pako`](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/) which is a `zlib` port to client-side javascript and use the [`ungzip()`](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/#ungzip) or [`inflate()`](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/#inflate) function to decompress your json file. Once it has been decompressed, you can simply import your resulting file into your code like such:

```
import jsonFile from 'resultingFile.json'
```

Comment: It makes sense, but every sample I found on the internet does that...
I going to change 'fs' for 'fetch', I think that's what I truly need.
I just need to get a file.json.gzip from my public folder and read it.
Any sugestions?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No worries, by experience I do all my file processing server-side so I use [`zlib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) but again, it is node.js- specific. I can suggest [pako](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/) which is a `zlib` port to client-side javascript and use the [`ungzip()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zlib) function to decompress your json file. Once it has been decompressed, you can simply import your resulting file into your code like such: `import jsonFile from 'resultingFile.json'`

Comment: It seems I linked the wrong documentation for the `ungzip()` function. [Here is the right one](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/#ungzip) or you can also use [`inflate()`](http://nodeca.github.io/pako/#inflate)

Comment: Hi @JKleinne, I'm using pako like you suggested to inflate(unzip) the file, http.get to get the file from the server public folder. Everything is working perfectly now. Thanks for your help, you're very kind.

Comment: Hey @GabrielMarcondes, no worries glad everything worked out for you!